# How to handle the back button after logout in webpages

Tags: python, html, django-rest-framework

i am developing 2 webpages login, home.Once i login with valid credentials, going to home page and able to see the profile information.And when i click on logout i am coming to Login screen.But when i click on back button, again it's going to home screen.So please tell me how to handle this scenario or how to disable the back button of browser when we logout. My source lode looks like below.

```
def checkLogin(request):
  login = LoginForm(request.POST)
  usr = UserForm()
  try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.data['username'])
  except User.DoesNotExist:
    user = None  
  if user:
    if user.password == request.data['password']:
        request.session['is_logged_in']=True
        request.session['username']=user.username
        res = get_tokens_for_user(user)
        print('token is',res)
        request.session['token']= res['access']
        updateMemberWithToken(user.username,res['access'])
        updateMemberWithLogeedAt(user.username,res['access'])
        context = {'form':usr,'user':user}
        return render(request,'home.html',context)
    messages.success(request, 'Username and Password are not matched')
    return render(request,'login.html',{'form':login})   
messages.success(request,'User is not available')
return render(request,'login.html',{'form':login})
```

And logout button source is

```
function logout(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Here we go on the new page
        document.write(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
        xhr.open("POST","/site/logout/");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer dfdfdfgdfgdfgdfdfgd' ); 
        xhr.send({'username':user.username});
        return false;
    }
```

And logout function in views.py is

```
@cache_control(no_cache=True,must_revalidate=True)
@protected_resource()    
@api_view(['POST'])
def logout(request):
  request.session.flush()
  login = LoginForm()
  updateMemberWithToken(request.data['username'],'')
  response = HttpResponseRedirect('/')
  for cookie in request.COOKIES:
     print(cookie)
     response.delete_cookie(cookie)
  django.logout(request)    
  return response
```

Comment: please provide code and error messages please

Comment: You can go to the home screen when you press the back button. That's not an issue. The issue is if you can perform any action there. Because when you click the back button, the browser loads the page from memory and does not make any API call. If you have added protections in your views, this will not be any issue.